# How to get bandwidth from ifconfig eth0 on win7

Tags: python-2.7, windows-7, bandwidth, ifconfig

i'm still confusing find bandwidth `value` using `ifconfig eth0` , because it's very different if i see tutorial from **os linux** but my pc still os **window 7** ..
Is there any other way to find bandwidth `value` in **window 7** ? 
because i must find **byte** from `ifconfig` for convert to **Kbps**

Answer (score 0):

problem solved `C:\windows\system32\ipconfig` on `cmd`

Comment: I must check bandwidth byte from `ifconfig eth0` but on windows is to be `ipconfig` last, i must convert byte from bandwitdh into Kbps. I have a little practice, for make bandwitdh monitor by `script.py`